# Request for javascript that open multiple link at once

Tags: javascript, url, browser

I wish there is a javascript code which I can copy and paste into my browser's address bar to open multiple websites at once in different tabs.

Answer (score 3):

```
javascript:var urls = ['http://www.google.com','http://www.stackoverflow.com']; for (i=0;i<urls.length;i++) window.open(urls[i]);
```

Comment: Or on newer browsers: `javascript:['http://www.google.com','http://www.stackoverflow.com'].map(open)`